# Is it possible to port a plugin sdk written in C++ to C# .net?

Tags: c#, c++, plugins, translate

I have this plugin sdk for this program I am using and I really want to write it in C#. Is it possible to port the C++ code into C# code which then I can use to build a program in C#? The sdk is very small only containing about 1500 lines of code in which most of those lines are either comments or just constants which i can just copy exactly.
I asking here becuase I dont want to waste my time trying to translate the code just to realise its not going to end up working

Comment: Short answer: Yes, you can port anything from C++ to C#

Comment: There are some functions that use __stdcall and some other callbacks, how would I got about porting those functions? Would I have to make a C++ dll with the functions then import that dll with the callback of the function and pinvoke?

example of a func used in the sdk:
 `virtual int _stdcall ProcessParam(int Index, int Value, int RECFlags) = 0; `

Comment: A plugin SDK usually describes a binary contract between the host and a plugin. Do you want too keep this unmanaged interface or do you want to replace it by a managed interface? In the first case: which of the two sides (host or plugin) do you want to port to C#?